# How to show print margin/vertical line in EmbeddedEditor?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, xtext

I want to show a vertical line (print margin in eclipse wording) after 120 characters in my `org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.embedded.EmbeddedEditor`. Is this supported somehow or is there some underlying editor available where I could create such a line?

Comment: The ordinary text editor uses `org.eclipse.jface.text.MarginPainter` for this. I don't know if that is suitable for xText.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from [greg-449s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2670892/greg-449) comment:

```
    final EmbeddedEditor editor = ...;
    editor.createPartialEditor();

    MarginPainter marginPainter = new MarginPainter(editor.getViewer());
    marginPainter.setMarginRulerColumn(120);
    marginPainter.setMarginRulerColor(Display.getDefault().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_GRAY));
    editor.getViewer().addPainter(marginPainter);
```

You have to set the color, otherwise the next call to `paint()` will throw.